# Query CosmosDB from Azure Function .csx

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, document-database, csx

I want to query a CosmosDB collection to see if a document already exists from within a Azure Function using csx.

As well as the following code I have an implicit binding towards the cosmosDB collection to be able to create new documents. This is done using

```
binder.BindAsync<IAsyncCollector<string>>(new CosmosDBAttribute("test", "collection")
```

This a simple version of my function.

```
#r "System"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

public static async Task<string> Run(string localityId, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    ...

    string EndpointUrl = "<your endpoint URL>";
    string PrimaryKey = "<your primary key>";
    DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey);

    ...
}
```

This results in the following error message:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocumentClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have installed the extension `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB`

I am running on MacOS using the `func host start` command to test locally.

Answer (score 1):

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocumentClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems that you need to reference **#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"**. You also could get demo code from [Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---c-script-example)

```
 #r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"

    using System;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
    {
      log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
      log.Verbose("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
    }
```

**Update:**

To use NuGet packages in a C# function, upload a project.json file to the function's folder in the function app's file system. Here is an example project.json file that adds a reference

[image]

Comment: This is not working. The reference #r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client" gives med the error:

`Compilation service error 
[03/07/2018 09:39:25] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: C# compilation service error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
[03/07/2018 09:39:25] . System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Still the same error. I am running this locally, do I need to run a install command or similar?

Comment: If it is run in locally, it is different from azure portal. It is a precompiled azure function. You need to install [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) to your function

Comment: I tried running `nuget install Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` inside the function folder. This downloaded the package, but my function still returns the same error. `The type or namespace name 'Documents' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: If there is a snapshot will be more helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166386/discussion-between-lundmarkus-and-tom-sun).